# Zebra widget doesn't work, if i have a child table?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have a  problems with the JQuery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo) plugin.

I use "zebra" widget, but it doesn't work if i have another table in the main table.

```
$("#selection_table").tablesorter(
     {
          widgets: ['zebra']
        })
```

if i have another table somewhere in the `selection_table`, zebra widget stop working properly.

Is there a way to fix such behavior?

Thanks much

Comment: I think you'd have to write your own version of the widget. That one doesn't notice when it crosses down the DOM into another table. I think it could be fixed easily by changing `$("tr:visible",table.tBodies[0])` to `$(table.tBodies[0]).children('tr:visible')` or something close.

Comment: In what application would you ever have a table *inside* a table?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you can do here, the code isn't correct, here's the widget:

```
ts.addWidget({
    id: "zebra",
    format: function(table) {
        if (table.config.debug) {
            var time = new Date();
        }
        $("tr:visible", table.tBodies[0]).filter(':even').removeClass(table.config.widgetZebra.css[1]).addClass(table.config.widgetZebra.css[0]).end().filter(':odd').removeClass(table.config.widgetZebra.css[0]).addClass(table.config.widgetZebra.css[1]);
        if (table.config.debug) {
            $.tablesorter.benchmark("Applying Zebra widget", time);
        }
    }
});
```

that `$("tr:visible", table.tBodies[0])` *should* be:  `$(table.tBodies[0]).children("tr:visible")` to do odd/even correctly.